# Combine file upload and request body on a single endpoint in rest controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The UI for my webapp has the ability to either upload a file(csv), or send the data as json in request body. However either a file upload, or a json request would be present in the request and not both. I am creating a spring rest controller which combine file upload and also accepts the request json values as well.

With the below endpoint tested from postman, I am not getting exception:

**org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found**

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MovieController.class);

@PostMapping(value="/movies", consumes = {"multipart/form-data", "application/json"})
public void postMovies( @RequestPart String movieJson, @RequestPart(value = "moviesFile") MultipartFile movieFile ) {

    // One of the below value should be present and other be null
    LOGGER.info("Movies Json Body {}", movieJson);
    LOGGER.info("Movies File Upload {}", movieFile);
}
```

}

Appreciate any help in getting this issue solved?

Note: I was able to build two separate endpoint for file upload and json request, but that won't suffice my requirement. Hence I'm looking for a solution to combine both

Comment: Are you setting the `content-type` in your postman request? If so, don't. Uncheck the `content-type` and let the postman app take care of it.

Comment: @k9yosh Nopes, I checked that way too.. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/movies", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data", "application/json" })
public void postMovies(
        @RequestParam(value = "moviesFile", required = false) MultipartFile file, 
  UploadRequestBody request) {
```

In RequestBody you can add the parameters you want to send.
This will not send the data as JSON.
Edit:- I forgot to add the variable for the Multipart file and I mistakenly used the RequestBody which is reserved keyword in spring.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code is wrong please check. Also, you can't send the file as a request parameter, so your usage of `@RequestParam` is wrong. Also, your understanding of how multipart files work is incorrect to my knowledge. Please refer [This for more details on how multipart works](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Comment: @k9yosh, we certainly can use the multipart file as a request param. Please check this example https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create two separate endpoints. This splits and isolates the different functionality and reduces the complexity of your code. In addition testing would be easier and provides better readability.

Your client actually has to know which variable to use. So just choose different endpoints for your request instead of using different variables for the same endpoint.

```java
@PostMapping(value="/movies-file-upload", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void postMoviesFile(@RequestPart(value = "moviesFile") MultipartFile movieFile ) {

    LOGGER.info("Movies File Upload {}", movieFile);
}

@PostMapping(value="/movies-upload", consumes = {"application/json"})
public void postMoviesJson( @RequestPart String movieJson) {

    LOGGER.info("Movies Json Body {}", movieJson);
}
```